# limit the loading of a web page php

Tags: php, load, limit

I need to stop the loading of a web page if the loading take too much time to execute the order. Basically, if the time of execution is more than 20 second, i want to stop the loading of the page and redirect the user.

I would use set_time_default well, but it don't returns value -> http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: How you are triggering order execnution? Click on link or button etc?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a more advanced way to trap that event.

Take a look at this question, particularly Frank Farmer's brilliant answer: [Php trapping maximun execution time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678466/php-trapping-maximun-execution-time-error)